# Is there a way to attach a file?

Tags: support, status-declined

Is there a way to attach a file such as .txt or .xlsx to my question? If not then what no-cost alternatives do I have?

BTW I work at a high security national laboratory so I can not post it online here and provide a link to it.

Comment: If you could attach a file here it would be exposed to the world, so what's the problem with posting it somewhere else and providing a link?

Comment: @whuber. I see your point. I guess I just had never posted anything online outside of the capability that is provided here at work. But I now see I can use something like Google Docs and just provide a link to it. Still it would have been one less step if the ability to add attachments where there to begin with.

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not possible to post a file into a question, at least not directly into the SE software. It's largely because this would post a security risk -- the file could be corrupted or infected, and we'd need to include some sort of virus check for each file. This, in turn, would affect our performance. Please see [this meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4637/please-add-a-system-to-allow-file-uploads-attached-to-questions-and-answers) for more information.

That said: you're free to link to Google Docs or some other file hosting service should you need to include a file with your question for whatever reason.